# OpenGL overlapping vertex attributes

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, vertex-shader

I like to generate flat shading triangle normales in the vertex shader. To do this, I need to access the current, and the two next vertices attributes in the current vertex shader. Obviously this can be done by a geometry shader, but those don't exist in GL ES for example.

So is there any way to make GLSL access three consecutive vertex positions, but only advance by one position in every vertex invocation? Otherwise I would have to assign the data of three vertices to every vertex.. a vast overhead.

Comment: Why don't you pre-calculate that normal/color, and store it in the buffer as well as the vertices?

Comment: I don't like to store all the normals that can easily be obtained by the triangles vertex position... Even if I store them, I would only have one normal for three vertices, so how to access them 3 times? The same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Accessing multiple vertices isn't possible in the vertex shader.  If you want to create flat shading, you need to replicate your vertices, so that you have a seperate copy of the vertex for each surface normal you will need (one for each face that shares that vertex position).  This is probably the solution you'd need for OpenGL ES.

Alternatively, if you are targeting OpenGL 4.x you can use the concept of the [provoking vertex](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glProvokingVertex.xml), which allows you to specify a vertex for which the attributes should be re-used across all the vertices of the face.  The attributes affected are only those which have the `flat` keyword associated with them in the shader source.

Comment: This doesn't address my main problem, that I doesn't like to have the normal included in vertex data at all.. As it is easily computable if more then one vertex is available, I thought it should be possible. However, it seems a geometry shader would be needed.

Comment: If `glVertexAttribPointer` is used three times with a too-small `stride`, and three different offsets, each bound attribute would give a different vertex from the sequence. However, for getting the data grouped by primitives, one would need to get a series of five vertices and select the right one out of them by the primitive id I guess. Question is, if this gets optimized well, or creates five times the bandwith needed for one vertex feed... Of course it don't have to do so...

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding.  The solution I'm proposing is that you stop trying to optimize for the number of vertices in your buffers.  If you have a logical vertex that appears in N faces, each of which has a different surface normal, than that vertex position should appear in your position buffer N times, with the other buffers having the corresponding color / surface normal / whatever at that given index.